# Error: Property [kpi_description] does not exist on this collection instancein Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this code:

Controller

```
public function index()
{
  $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
  $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->get();

  return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')->with('goals', $goals);
}
```

model

```
class AppraisalGoal extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'appraisal_goals';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
              'weighted_score',
              'employee_comment',
              'goal_title',
          ];

  public function appraisalgoaldetail(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalDetail');
  }
}

class AppraisalGoalDetail extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'appraisal_goal_details';
 protected $fillable = [
              'kpi_description',
          ];

 public function appraisalgoal()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoal');
}     
}
```

the function **appraisalgoaldetail()** is hasMany relationtionship.

view

```
 @foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
    <td>
      {{$key+1}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{$goal->appraisalgoaldetail->kpi_description ?? '' }}
    </td>                            
    <td>
       {{$goal->goal_title ?? '' }}
    </td>
 @endforeach
```

When I ran the code, I got this error:

> Property [kpi_description] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\accly\resources\views\appraisal_goals\index.blade.php)

How do I resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: You've already mentioned that `appraisalgoaldetail` is a `hasMany` relationship so `$goal->appraisalgoaldetail` is going to return a collection. Is the `kpi_description` going to be the same for every appraisalgoaldetails that a goal has? Or does a goal only ever has one `appraisalgoaldetail`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you written HasMany relation with AppraisalGoal and AppraisalGoalDetail.
So 
`$goal->appraisalgoaldetail`
 will be resulted in an array. As a result you are trying to get the `kpi_description` from an array. I think this is the problem you are facing.

For find out the problem try

```
@foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
<td>
  {{$key+1}}
</td>
<td>
  {{$goal->appraisalgoaldetail[0]['kpi_description'] ?? '' }}
</td>                            
<td>
   {{$goal->goal_title ?? '' }}
</td>
@endforeach
```

Or use a foreach like

```
@foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
<td>
  {{$key+1}}
</td>
<td>
  @foreach($goal->appraisalgoaldetail as $app)
    <div>{{ $app->appraisalgoaldetail }}</div>
  @endforeach
</td>                            
<td>
   {{$goal->goal_title ?? '' }}
</td>


@endforeach
```